# Prevent BoxShadow from being clipped by parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building my own material-like card with a box shadow. I want to have several of these combined in a `PageView`, so that I can swipe between cards - each `Card` should fill out the entire width of the screen.
The cards are having a `BoxShadow` as decoration, however when inserting the `Card` into the `PageView` (or any other wrapping widget), the `BoxShadow` will disappear as it is clipped by the `PageView`'s bounding box.

This can be fixed by wrapping the `Card` into a `Padding`, but that's not what I want since I prefer the padding to be given by the outermost widget to all child widgets of that entire view - so that in case my padding ever changes I don't have to change every single widget.

This is how my `Card` code looks like:

```
class Card extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  Card({@required this.child, this.padding});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1), blurRadius: 14.0),
        BoxShadow(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
            offset: Offset(0, 2),
            blurRadius: 2.0)
      ]),
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding ?? EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: this.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wrapping several of these results in the described clipping behavior.

**Is there a way of telling Flutter not to clip whatever is "leaking" out of the bounding box?**
The same behavior happens when positioning widgets on a stack out of bounce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use margins:

```
...
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10), 
..
```

Maybe you would be interested with viewportFraction PageController  argument:

```
final PageController controller = PageController(
  viewportFraction: 1,
);
...
PageView.builder(
  controller: controller,
```

It shrinks a size of the page in PageView, so nearest pages become visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exact issue is the parent clipping the child. In `PageView`, `clipBehavior` defaults to `Clip.hardEdge`. So setting `clipBehavior` to `clipBehavior.none` should prevent the clipping.